# Changing variables: partial derivatives of a tensor

Tags: partial-derivative, coordinate-systems, tensors

Given is the tensor $T$

in Cartesian coordinates $T=\operatorname{diag}\{T_{xx},T_{yy},T_{zz}\}$

in cylindrical coordinates $T=\operatorname{diag}\{T_{rr},T_{\theta\theta},T_{zz}\}$

How does one express $$\frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial \theta}$$ through $T_{xx},T_{yy},T_{zz}$ in Cartesian coordinates (no longer differentiating with respect to $r,\theta,z$ but with respect to $x,y,z$)?

If $T$ is a function, then one should use the chain rule, but how is this to be done when $T$ is a tensor?

To rephrase the question:

Let's say, in cylindrical coordinates $\frac{\partial T_{\theta \theta}}{\partial \theta}=0$. My question is - how do we express this same relation in Cartesian coordinates? It has to be a relation involving $T_{xx}, T_{yy},T_{zz}$ and the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial T_{ii}}{\partial x_j}$, where i,j are one of {x,y,z}

Answer (score 0):

You can view your tensor as a triplet of three functions $T_{xx}, T_{yy}, T_{zz}$. Each of these functions can be expressed in either Cartesian or cylindrical coordinates. Thus, $T_{zz} = T_{zz}(x, y, z) = T_{zz}(r, \theta, z)$. You want to express $\partial T_{zz}/\partial \theta$ in Cartesian coordinates. We therefore begin with 
\begin{equation}
dT_{zz} = \frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial z}dz
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial T_{zz}}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial\theta}
\end{equation}
You can repeat if for other components of the tensor.

Comment: The problem is that the tensor itself transforms under the change of coordinates. That is, $T$ cannot be seen as composed of functions. The transformation law is given here

http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En221/Notes/Polar_Coords/Polar_Coords.htm

(see 2.7 Converting tensors between Cartesian and Spherical-Polar bases)

Comment: @Zack, the question asked for how to express a certain derivative in terms of Cartesian coordinates. What you are referring to is the expression for gradient (and other derivatives) in other coordinates. The two are different. If you are interested in expressing $\nabla \mathbb{T}$ in spherical polar or cylindrical coordinates, then your link gives the correct expressions.

Comment: The link shows that a tensor with a matrix $T$ in one coordinate system and $T^{\prime}$ in another transforms as $T^{\prime}=A^{-1}TA$, where $A$ is the the transformation matrix between the two coordinate bases. (Cartesian and cylindrical). True, the question is about a derivative, but this is a derivative of a tensor $T$ which also transforms under a coordinate change.

Comment: @Zack, all that you are saying is correct. But if that was what you were looking for, then it would have helped if you has asked how to write gradient, divergence and curl of a tensor in cylindrical coordinates. The transformation $T^\prime = A^{-1}TA$ is the definition of tensor. The matrix $A$ in this does not transform Cartesian to cylindrical but is an orthogonal matrix, representing a rotation.

Comment: In the link, section 2.4: "Converting vectors between Cylindrical and Cartesian bases" we read: "The transformation matrix..." ==> A is the transformation matrix between the bases. 
The question is not about $\nabla$, curl or other operators. I will add more to the question to make this more clear.